# Display an image hover a webpage with a browser extension

Tags: javascript, html, json, manifest

I'm currently trying to develop my first chrome extension. What I want to do is pretty basic.

On click on a button (in the extension toolbox) => I would like to display an image (png) hover the current webpage.

For now I have the image displaying in the extension toolbox (see the screenshot).

How can I set the display context in the webpage instead?

Actual Code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var checkPageButton = document.getElementById('checkPage');
  checkPageButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "myImg.png";
    img.setAttribute("style", "background-repeat: repeat-y");
    document.body.appendChild(img);
  }, false);
}, false);
```

Here's the actual behaviour.

[image]

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You probably want to use a contentscript instead of an extension page.